# Search bar width is very small

Tags: java, android, search, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I am using a custom search bar  in my android app. The problem is that when the search bar is in focus its width is very small (like wrap_content) in spite of there is extra space in the action bar. But when the focus is gone full text is shown. Also the soft keyboard appears on touching the text entered (short or long). When the text is short the keyboard does not appear on touching the extra space remaining on the right side of the text, but it does appear when the text is long.
I want the EditText (Search bar) width be as long as possible like match_parent as there is enough space. Any suggestion? [Short text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQGjY.jpg) [Long text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2eVN.jpg)

This is search_bar.xml

```
<EditText
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/et_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

This is my_menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="@string/share_this_app"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:title="@string/rate_this_app"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_rate">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:title="@string/about"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_about">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/more_apps"
    android:title="@string/more_apps"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_apps">
</item>
```

This is onCreateOptionMenu() method

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.more_apps);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    return true;
}
```

This is handleSearch() method

```
private void handleMenuSearch() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); //get the actionbar

    if (isSearchOpened) { //test if the search is open
        if (actionBar != null) {
            if (et_search.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                et_search.getText().clear();
                doSearch(et_search.getText().toString()); //Clears the previous highlights
                //open the keyboard focused in the et_Search
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm != null) {
                    imm.showSoftInput(et_search, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
            } else {
                et_search.getText().clear();
                doSearch(et_search.getText().toString()); //Clears the previous highlights
                actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false); //disable a custom view inside the actionbar
                actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); //show the title in the actionbar

                //hides the keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm != null) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et_search.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }

                //add the search icon in the actionbar
                mSearchAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_open_search));

                isSearchOpened = false;
            }
        }
    } else { //open the search entry
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); //enable it to display a custom view in the
            //action bar
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar); //add the custom view
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //hide the title

            et_search = actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.et_search); //the text editor
        }

        //this is a listener to do a search when the user clicks on search button
        et_search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    doSearch(et_search.getText().toString());
                    //hides the keyboard
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    if (imm != null) {
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et_search.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        et_search.requestFocus();

        //open the keyboard focused in the et_Search
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.showSoftInput(et_search, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }

        //add the close icon
        mSearchAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_close_search));

        isSearchOpened = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
if (isSearchOpened) { //test if the search is open
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false); //disable a custom view inside the actionbar
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); //show the title in the action bar
            // your other codes
        }
}
```

I mean make it common when `isSearchOpened==true` and `actionbar!=null` instead only for the else condition

Comment: Thanks for your response @Amit K. Saha, but it's not working